# Given a list of N integers, how to find out if the second derivative is positive or negative?

Tags: calculus, statistics

Let's say I have a list where N=10, such as [45,34,56,22,33,44,34,34,43,35].

I would like to know if the second derivative is positive or negative, in other words, if the rate of change of these numbers is itself increasing or decreasing.

I took calculus in college 20 years ago. I would know how to do that if I had a function but I don't remember how that can be accomplished with just samples.

Can someone explain me the rationale behind the process?

Comment: Your function has to be well-defined. One method forward would be to fit a polynomial of degree 9 where $f(0) = 45$, $f(1) = 34$, etc., and solving for the coefficients. As it stands, we just have a list of numbers which tells us nothing about the function you are studying.

Answer (score 1):

I will probably plot the points on an x-y axis, find a polynomial (or exponential regression) and take the second derivative of the function that approximate the data. Alternative:you could use numerical differentiation, but you will need to take more points.
you need to evaluate:
$$ f'(x) \approx \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$
for $h$ very small (if you are doing engineering or physics calculations $ h \approx 10^-3$ 
or much smaller.

Comment: How to find the approximate polynomial that is a good fit for my list of values?

Comment: You can use different software (like excel, matlab, or even a simple casio calculator), but it clearly depends on your data. More info:http://www.arachnoid.com/polysolve/

Comment: @Becky I'll post an example of a method.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give an example of generating a polynomial to fit 3 points and you can generalize.

Say our points were $f(0) = 1, f(1) = 4, f(2) = 6$.

Then we could say we have a polynomial $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2$ and solve by subbing in values of $x$. In this case we would have, $f(0) = a_0 = 1$ and $f(1) = a_0 + a_1 + a_2 = 4$ and $f(2) = a_0 + 2a_1 + 4a_2 = 6$. You could solve these directly or use a matrix as so

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 & 6} = & \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 2 & 4 & 5} \\ = & \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & -1} \\ = & \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2}} \\ = & \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{7}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2}}\end{aligned} \end{equation}.$$

Thus our equation would be $f(x) = 1 + \frac{7}{2}x - \frac{1}{2}x^2$. This method can generalize to any set of data points. Also, notice that this function is differentiable.

**EDIT**

Here is wolframalpha's generation of [your polynomial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+%7B0%2C45%7D%2C+%7B1%2C34%7D%2C+%7B2%2C56%7D%2C+%7B3%2C22%7D%2C+%7B4+%2C33%7D%2C+%7B5+%2C44%7D%2C+%7B6%2C+34%7D%2C%7B+7%2C+34%7D%2C%7B+8%2C43%7D%2C%7B9%2C+35%7D).

Comment: Thank you so much, Chantry. Would you mind explaining me or pointing to a site where I can refresh my mind how to solve the matrix?

Comment: I used [Gaussian Ellimination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2j5Ic2V7wq4). Alternatively, you could just not represent it as a matrix and solve the equations by subbing in directly. Note that I did post the full solution to your polynomial below my edit.